# Quickblox Enterprise + Swift 3.0 + iOS 10+, QBRequest renaming chat dialog incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift3, quickblox

I am attempting to set the name of the chat dialog on the QB server to a custom name. Yet whenever I send the parameters after chatDialog.setValue(roomName, forKey: "name") it renames the private chat dialog to the name of the occupant ID I used to create the room.

```
let qbUser = QBUUser()
        qbUser.id = DataModel.sharedInstance.qbLoginParams.id
        qbUser.password = DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.QBPassword
        QBChat.instance().connect(with: qbUser) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            } else {
                print("success connecting to QB chat")
            }

            let chatDialog: QBChatDialog = QBChatDialog(dialogID: nil, type: QBChatDialogType.private)
            chatDialog.occupantIDs = []
            //chatDialog.occupantIDs?.append(NSNumber(value: DataModel.sharedInstance.qbLoginParams.id))
            chatDialog.occupantIDs?.append(12186)
            chatDialog.setValue(roomName, forKey: "name")

            print(chatDialog)

            QBRequest.createDialog(chatDialog, successBlock: {(response: QBResponse?, createdDialog: QBChatDialog?) in
                print("<------------------------------<<< Success creating chat dialog")
                print(response ?? "No Response")
                print(createdDialog ?? "No Created Dialog")
            }, errorBlock: {(response: QBResponse!) in
                print("<------------------------------<<< Error creating chat dialog")
                print(response ?? "No Response")
            })

        }
```

This is perplexing as I clearly set the name of the room before making the request to create and I can see it in the POST parameters in the console yet the response names it incorrectly. Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: `@note If chat type is private, name will be nil.` from the doc of `QBChatDialog` may explains this?

Comment: But in the admin panel it labels the room as the other opponents name. If I can't name it thats fine but if that was true then why does it get that name then?

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth, You can't change the name of the private dialog. The name of the private dialog is just the opponent's name.

Comment: @Guru_quickblox_support That should definitely be in your documentation somewhere considering the intellisense lets me set the value. When will you update your code to Swift 3.0? Any plans for that? Its really a pain to have to do that myself every time I need a code block.

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth, [documentation reference 1](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Create_dialog), [documentation reference 2](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Dialog_model)

Comment: @ErikGrosskurth, "When will you update your code to Swift 3.0? Any plans for that? Its really a pain to have to do that myself every time I need a code block" Could you please specify what code should we update to Swift 3.0?

Comment: Umm... All of it?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out even though intellisense lets you set the name the DB overwrites it as the opponent name in a type: 3 chat session. I had to switch to a  type: 2 or Group type to make it happen.

```
let chatDialog: QBChatDialog = QBChatDialog(dialogID: nil, type: QBChatDialogType.group)
```

Apparently you can only access the opponent ID's if you have been added anyways so it wasn't a big deal in my case.